# Debug Rails Active Record Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way debug ActiveRecord queries before they are executed rather than after?

Comment: depends on how you want to debug, you want to know the sql statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call .to_sql on the end of the query to output the sql that it generates like so:

```
SomeModel.where(:stuff => 'is here').to_sql
```